# PHP Files being downloaded instead of displayed in browser

Tags: centos, nginx, php

I created a **VPS** using Nginx and I tried to display the php info with: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Instead, the browser asks me to download the php file, and it's not parsed either.

This happens only on my VPS websites located in `/var/www/`. The same php file located in the default `/usr/share/nginx/html` (accessed by the browser by ip) shows up OK (and display in browser instead of asking to be downloaded).

Here are my config files:

**virtual.conf**

```
#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

server {
    listen       80;
#    listen       *:80;
    server_name  website.com www.website.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/website.com/public_html/;
         index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/website.com/public_html/;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

**default.conf**

```
#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name 100.00.000.000;


    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: For my own sanity, can you remove the trailing slash from the working location:root declaration (root           /var/www/website.com/public_html/;). I couldn't quickly determine from documentation if that's translated differently.

Comment: Sure, why can't I use trailing slashes though?

Comment: Wow that solved the issue! I thought the trailing slash was just a "bad form" thing but I didn't expect that to be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, you needed to add the trailing slash to make it work, right?

Comment: yess sirr, that was the issue